# Matlab: how to solve a one order PDE (diffusion equation)

Tags: matlab, pde

Following is a pde of the diffusion equation. Its second order was eliminated, since D = 0.
I am new learner of the matlab, knowing that the diffusion equation has certain similarity with the heat equation, but I don't know how to apply the method in my solution.

Please send your suggestions. Thanks with all my heart.

Also, if the D is a tensor while D11 neq D12 neq D21 neq D22, then, how to solve my problem?

***a = epsilon = 0.1, T0 = 5.0 , b = 0.1,  c = 100***

Diffusion equation:
[image]

F(x1, x2) & F2(x1, x2):
[image]

Comment: Here is a page on some of the DE functionality in Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1500/1510.html I only have some limited experience with Matlab's ODE solvers, but they have some PDE pointers on there as well. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to love the MathWorks's help:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pdepe.html is the help page for `pdepe`, which solves parabolic PDEs (i.e., the heat equation) via the finite element method.